# Flutter Web and Firebase with Multi Environment

Tags: firebase, web, flutter-web, environment

I started a Flutter Web project and used Firebase Auth, Firestore, Hosting, Functions and Storage. I have two different Firebase project for this app; one of them is for development, the other of them is for product. How can I manage this environments like Android Product Flavor or iOS Schemes?

When I searched on Google, I saw Firebase Environment and used it, but it is not clear for me. For example, if I manage this situation with Firebase Environment, how can I understand which firebase project is used in dart code and change some of codes according to flavor?